# D3 Partition with labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I got the example from [this page](http://bl.ocks.org/vgrocha/1580af34e56ee6224d33) that's actually works very good !
But as you can see, there is a lot of labels that's up-side-down.
[image]

Is there some how to prevent the up-side-down labels ? I've this running on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qMwXbV17OMujPt8xEXPH), but bellow are the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

  circle,
  path {
  cursor: pointer;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#tooltip { background-color: white;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;

}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>

var margin = {top: 350, right: 480, bottom: 350, left: 480},
  radius = Math.min(margin.top, margin.right, margin.bottom, margin.left) - 10;

function filter_min_arc_size_text(d, i) {return (d.dx*d.depth*radius/3)>14};

var hue = d3.scale.category10();

var luminance = d3.scale.sqrt()
  .domain([0, 1e6])
  .clamp(true)
  .range([90, 20]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
  .sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name); })
  .size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx - .01 / (d.depth + .5); })
  .innerRadius(function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })
  .outerRadius(function(d) { return radius / 3 * (d.depth + 1) - 1; });

//Tooltip description
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("id", "tooltip")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("z-index", "10")
  .style("opacity", 0);

function format_number(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}


function format_description(d) {
  var description = d.description;
  return  '<b>' + d.name + '</b></br>'+ d.description + '<br> (' + format_number(d.value) + ')';
}

function computeTextRotation(d) {
  var angle=(d.x +d.dx/2)*180/Math.PI - 90

  return angle;
}

function mouseOverArc(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("stroke","black")

  tooltip.html(format_description(d));
  return tooltip.transition()
    .duration(50)
    .style("opacity", 0.9);
}

function mouseOutArc(){
  d3.select(this).attr("stroke","")
  return tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
}

function mouseMoveArc (d) {
  return tooltip
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
}

var root_ = null;
d3.json("flare-labeled.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  // Compute the initial layout on the entire tree to sum sizes.
  // Also compute the full name and fill color for each node,
  // and stash the children so they can be restored as we descend.

  partition
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
    .nodes(root)
    .forEach(function(d) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.sum = d.value;
      d.key = key(d);
      d.fill = fill(d);
    });

  // Now redefine the value function to use the previously-computed sum.
  partition
    .children(function(d, depth) { return depth < 2 ? d._children : null; })
    .value(function(d) { return d.sum; });

  var center = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", radius / 3)
    .on("click", zoomOut);

  center.append("title")
    .text("zoom out");

  var partitioned_data=partition.nodes(root).slice(1)

  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(partitioned_data)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; })
    .each(function(d) { this._current = updateArc(d); })
    .on("click", zoomIn)
    .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
    .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
    .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc);


  var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(partitioned_data)
    .enter().append("text")
    .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })
    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align  
    .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})

  function zoomIn(p) {
    if (p.depth > 1) p = p.parent;
    if (!p.children) return;
    zoom(p, p);
  }

  function zoomOut(p) {
    if (!p.parent) return;
    zoom(p.parent, p);
  }

  // Zoom to the specified new root.
  function zoom(root, p) {
    if (document.documentElement.__transition__) return;

    // Rescale outside angles to match the new layout.
    var enterArc,
      exitArc,
      outsideAngle = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

    function insideArc(d) {
      return p.key > d.key
        ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 0, dx: 0} : p.key < d.key
          ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 2 * Math.PI, dx: 0}
          : {depth: 0, x: 0, dx: 2 * Math.PI};
    }

    function outsideArc(d) {
      return {depth: d.depth + 1, x: outsideAngle(d.x), dx: outsideAngle(d.x + d.dx) - outsideAngle(d.x)};
    }

    center.datum(root);

    // When zooming in, arcs enter from the outside and exit to the inside.
    // Entering outside arcs start from the old layout.
    if (root === p) enterArc = outsideArc, exitArc = insideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

    var new_data=partition.nodes(root).slice(1)

    path = path.data(new_data, function(d) { return d.key; });

    // When zooming out, arcs enter from the inside and exit to the outside.
    // Exiting outside arcs transition to the new layout.
    if (root !== p) enterArc = insideArc, exitArc = outsideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

    d3.transition().duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750).each(function() {
      path.exit().transition()
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.depth === 1 + (root === p) ? 1 : 0; })
        .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, exitArc(d)); })
        .remove();

      path.enter().append("path")
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.depth === 2 - (root === p) ? 1 : 0; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; })
        .on("click", zoomIn)
        .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
        .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
        .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc)
        .each(function(d) { this._current = enterArc(d); });


      path.transition()
        .style("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, updateArc(d)); });



    });


    texts = texts.data(new_data, function(d) { return d.key; })

    texts.exit()
      .remove()
    texts.enter()
      .append("text")

    texts.style("opacity", 0)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })
      .attr("dx", "6") // margin
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
      .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
      .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})
      .transition().delay(750).style("opacity", 1)


  }
});

function key(d) {
  var k = [], p = d;
  while (p.depth) k.push(p.name), p = p.parent;
  return k.reverse().join(".");
}

function fill(d) {
  var p = d;
  while (p.depth > 1) p = p.parent;
  var c = d3.lab(hue(p.name));
  c.l = luminance(d.sum);
  return c;
}

function arcTween(b) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, b);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}

function updateArc(d) {
  return {depth: d.depth, x: d.x, dx: d.dx};
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", margin.top + margin.bottom + "px");

</script>
```

flare-labeled.json

```
{
  "name": "flare",
  "description": "flare",
  "children": [
  {
    "name": "analytic",
    "description": "analytics",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "cluster",
        "description": "cluster",
        "children": [
          {"name": "Agglomer", "description": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
          {"name": "Communit", "description": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
          {"name": "Hierarch", "description": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
          {"name": "MergeEdg", "description": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "graph",
        "description": "graph",
        "children": [
          {"name": "Betweenn", "description": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
          {"name": "LinkDist", "description": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
          {"name": "MaxFlowM", "description": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
          {"name": "Shortest", "description": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
          {"name": "Spanning", "description": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "optimiza",
        "description": "optimization",
        "children": [
          {"name": "AspectRa", "description": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "animate",
    "description": "animate",
    "children": [
      {"name": "Easing", "description": "Easing", "size": 17010},
      {"name": "Function", "description": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
      {
        "name": "interpol",
        "description": "interpolate",
        "children": [
          {"name": "ArrayInt", "description": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
          {"name": "ColorInt", "description": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
          {"name": "DateInte", "description": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
          {"name": "Interpol", "description": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
          {"name": "MatrixIn", "description": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
          {"name": "NumberIn", "description": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
          {"name": "ObjectIn", "description": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
          {"name": "PointInt", "description": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
          {"name": "Rectangl", "description": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
        ]
      },
      {"name": "ISchedul", "description": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
      {"name": "Parallel", "description": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
      {"name": "Pause", "description": "Pause", "size": 449},
      {"name": "Schedule", "description": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
      {"name": "Sequence", "description": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
      {"name": "Transiti", "description": "Transition", "size": 9201},
      {"name": "Transer", "description": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
      {"name": "TransEve", "description": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
      {"name": "Tween", "description": "Tween", "size": 6006}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "data",
    "description": "data",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "converte",
        "description": "converters",
        "children": [
          {"name": "Converte", "description": "Converters", "size": 721},
          {"name": "Delimite", "description": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
          {"name": "GraphMLC", "description": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
          {"name": "IDataCon", "description": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
          {"name": "JSONConv", "description": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
        ]
      },
      {"name": "DataFiel", "description": "DataField", "size": 1759},
      {"name": "DataSche", "description": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
      {"name": "DataSet", "description": "DataSet", "size": 586},
      {"name": "DataSour", "description": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
      {"name": "DataTabl", "description": "DataTable", "size": 772},
      {"name": "DataUtil", "description": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "display",
    "description": "display",
    "children": [
      {"name": "DirtySpr", "description": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
      {"name": "LineSpri", "description": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
      {"name": "RectSpri", "description": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
      {"name": "TextSpri", "description": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "flex",
    "description": "flex",
    "children": [
      {"name": "FlareVis", "description": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "physics",
    "description": "physics",
    "children": [
      {"name": "DragForc", "description": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
      {"name": "GravityF", "description": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
      {"name": "IForce", "description": "IForce", "size": 319},
      {"name": "NBodyFor", "description": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
      {"name": "Particle", "description": "Particle", "size": 2822},
      {"name": "Simulati", "description": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
      {"name": "Spring", "description": "Spring", "size": 2213},
      {"name": "SpringFo", "description": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
    ]
  },

      {"name": "Minimum", "description": "Minimum", "size": 843},
      {"name": "Not", "description": "Not", "size": 1554},
      {"name": "Or", "description": "Or", "size": 970},
      {"name": "Query", "description": "Query", "size": 13896},
      {"name": "Range", "description": "Range", "size": 1594},
      {"name": "StringUt", "description": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
      {"name": "Sum", "description": "Sum", "size": 791},
      {"name": "Variable", "description": "Variable", "size": 1124},
      {"name": "Variance", "description": "Variance", "size": 1876},
      {"name": "Xor", "description": "Xor", "size": 1101}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "scale",
    "description": "scale",
    "children": [
      {"name": "IScaleMa", "description": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
      {"name": "LinearSc", "description": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
      {"name": "LogScale", "description": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
      {"name": "OrdinalS", "description": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
      {"name": "Quantile", "description": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
      {"name": "Quantita", "description": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
      {"name": "RootScal", "description": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
      {"name": "Scale", "description": "Scale", "size": 4268},
      {"name": "ScaleTyp", "description": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
      {"name": "TimeScal", "description": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "util",
    "description": "util",
    "children": [
      {"name": "Arrays", "description": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
      {"name": "Colors", "description": "Colors", "size": 10001},
      {"name": "Dates", "description": "Dates", "size": 8217},
      {"name": "Displays", "description": "Displays", "size": 12555},
      {"name": "Filter", "description": "Filter", "size": 2324},
      {"name": "Geometry", "description": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
      {
        "name": "heap",
        "description": "heap",
        "children": [
          {"name": "Fibonacc", "description": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
          {"name": "HeapNode", "description": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
        ]
      },
      {"name": "IEvaluab", "description": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
      {"name": "IPredica", "description": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
      {"name": "IValuePr", "description": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
      {
        "name": "math",
        "description": "math",
        "children": [
          {"name": "DenseMat", "description": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
          {"name": "IMatrix", "description": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
          {"name": "SparseMa", "description": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
        ]
      },
      {"name": "Maths", "description": "Maths", "size": 17705},
      {"name": "Orientat", "description": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
      {
        "name": "palette",
        "description": "palette",
        "children": [
          {"name": "ColorPal", "description": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
          {"name": "Palette", "description": "Palette", "size": 1229},
          {"name": "ShapePal", "description": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
          {"name": "SizePale", "description": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
        ]
      },
      {"name": "Property", "description": "Property", "size": 5559},
      {"name": "Shapes", "description": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
      {"name": "Sort", "description": "Sort", "size": 6887},
      {"name": "Stats", "description": "Stats", "size": 6557},
      {"name": "Strings", "description": "Strings", "size": 22026}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "vis",
    "description": "vis",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "axis",
        "description": "axis",
        "children": [
          {"name": "Axes", "description": "Axes", "size": 1302},
          {"name": "Axis", "description": "Axis", "size": 24593},
          {"name": "AxisGrid", "description": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
          {"name": "AxisLabe", "description": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
          {"name": "Cartesia", "description": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "controls",
        "description": "controls",
        "children": [
          {"name": "AnchorCo", "description": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
          {"name": "ClickCon", "description": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
          {"name": "Control", "description": "Control", "size": 1353},
          {"name": "ControlL", "description": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
          {"name": "DragCont", "description": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
          {"name": "ExpandCo", "description": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
          {"name": "HoverCon", "description": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
          {"name": "IControl", "description": "IControl", "size": 763},
          {"name": "PanZoomC", "description": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
          {"name": "Selectio", "description": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
          {"name": "TooltipC", "description": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "data",
        "description": "data",
        "children": [
          {"name": "Data", "description": "Data", "size": 20544},
          {"name": "DataList", "description": "DataList", "size": 19788},
          {"name": "DataSpri", "description": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
          {"name": "EdgeSpri", "description": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
          {"name": "NodeSpri", "description": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
          {
            "name": "render",
            "description": "render",
            "children": [
              {"name": "ArrowTyp", "description": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
              {"name": "EdgeRend", "description": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
              {"name": "IRendere", "description": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
              {"name": "ShapeRen", "description": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
            ]
          },
          {"name": "ScaleBin", "description": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
          {"name": "Tree", "description": "Tree", "size": 7147},
          {"name": "TreeBuil", "description": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "events",
        "description": "events",
        "children": [
          {"name": "DataEven", "description": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
          {"name": "Selectio", "description": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
          {"name": "TooltipE", "description": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
          {"name": "Visualiz", "description": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "legend",
        "description": "legend",
        "children": [
          {"name": "Legend", "description": "Legend", "size": 20859},
          {"name": "LegendIt", "description": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
          {"name": "LegendRa", "description": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "operator",
        "description": "operator",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "distorti",
            "description": "distortion",
            "children": [
              {"name": "BifocalD", "description": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
              {"name": "Distorti", "description": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
              {"name": "FisheyeD", "description": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "encoder",
            "description": "encoder",
            "children": [
              {"name": "ColorEnc", "description": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
              {"name": "Encoder", "description": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
              {"name": "Property", "description": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
              {"name": "ShapeEnc", "description": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
              {"name": "SizeEnco", "description": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "description": "filter",
            "children": [
              {"name": "FisheyeT", "description": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
              {"name": "GraphDis", "description": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
              {"name": "Visibili", "description": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
            ]
          },
          {"name": "IOperato", "description": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
          {
            "name": "label",
            "description": "label",
            "children": [
              {"name": "Labeler", "description": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
              {"name": "RadialLa", "description": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
              {"name": "StackedA", "description": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "layout",
            "description": "layout",
            "children": [
              {"name": "AxisLayo", "description": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
              {"name": "BundledE", "description": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
              {"name": "CircleLa", "description": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
              {"name": "CirclePa", "description": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
              {"name": "Dendrogr", "description": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
              {"name": "ForceDir", "description": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
              {"name": "IcicleTr", "description": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
              {"name": "Indented", "description": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
              {"name": "Layout", "description": "Layout", "size": 7881},
              {"name": "NodeLink", "description": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
              {"name": "PieLayou", "description": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
              {"name": "RadialTr", "description": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
              {"name": "RandomLa", "description": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
              {"name": "StackedA", "description": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
              {"name": "TreeMapL", "description": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
            ]
          },
          {"name": "Operator", "description": "Operator", "size": 2490},
          {"name": "OperatorL", "description": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
          {"name": "OperatorS", "description": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
          {"name": "OperatorSW", "description": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
          {"name": "SortOper", "description": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
        ]
      },
      {"name": "Visualiz", "description": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Like this http://bl.ocks.org/vigorousnorth/7331bb51d4f0c2ae0314?

Comment: This is very nice ! As you can see, this rotate a maximum of 90 degrees and will never upside down. I need something like this, but applicable on the partition.

Comment: You may also have a look at Gerardo's and my own answer to [*"D3.js rotate axis labels around the middle point"*](/q/42581308). Both approaches should be fairly easy to adapt to your own layout.